# Get first and third monday of each month - strtotime

Tags: date, time, calendar, strtotime

I'd like to automatically display first and third monday of every month on website. If current date is after the first Monday, only third monday has to be shown.

I have modified code found on a forum and have made some changes, yet due to limited php knowledge I'm not able to verify if it'll provide correct results.

```
$time = strtotime("first Monday of ".$monthname." ".$year); 
$time2 = strtotime("third Monday of ".$monthname." ".$year); 
{
    if ($time2 > $time) {
        echo date('d-m-Y',$time2)." ".$monthname;
    }
    else {
        echo date('d-m-Y',$time)." ".$monthname;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean but this should do what I think you want:

```
$time1 = strtotime("first Monday of {$monthname} {$year}"); 
$time2 = strtotime("third Monday of {$monthname} {$year}");
echo date('jS F Y', time() > $time1 ? $time2 : $time1); // e.g. 1st January 1970
```

The `time() > $time1 ? $time2 : $time1` is a ternary conditional which basically means

```
condition ? if_true : if_false
```

Going by the way you wrote it, I think you need to know that you can put variables inside double quotes, e.g.

```
$a = 'first';
echo "The $a day of the week"; // echoes 'The first day of the week
```

but not in single quotes, e.g.

```
$a = 'first';
echo 'The $a day of the week'; // echoes 'The $a day of the week.
```

I put curly braces around the variables out of convention as so that I can do

```
$a = 'first';
$b = 'variable';
echo "This is the {$a}_{$b}"; // Echoes 'This is the first_variable'
```

without the braces

```
echo "This is the $a_$b" // Undefined variable $a_
```

or

```
try {
    // Do something
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "There was an error and the message was {$ex->getMessage()}";
}
```